# Redirecting subdomain to subdomain folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm having trouble redirecting `subdomain.domain.com` to `subdomain.domain.com/folder`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [R=301]
```

This just keeps redirecting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You created an endless rewrite loop, since `^(.*)$` also matches `/folder/...`.

You need to add a condition to prevent the endless rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /folder/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Ohh... I see. Thanks, arkascha!
But now it redirects to subdomain.domain.com/folder/subdomain

Comment: The rules as posted above do not create such effect. Not sure what you see. Try clearing your browsers cache or make a "deep reload".